# Extra file with Same Name Created Automatically while writing a program in unix

Tags: ubuntu, unix, operating-systems, c

Some time while writing a program for example 
`convert.c` a file with same name followed by tiled(~) `convert.c~` gets created in same directory. why is this so and whats really happening .please explain .

Comment: which editor do you use?

Answer (score 1):

it's created by your c editor program
It's created when you open your c file. it's a temporary file. and it should be removed when you close your editor

Answer (score 1):

In Linux platform, when we use "vim" or "vi" swap file is created i.e. 
".filename.c.swp".

Swap file allows an operating system to use hard disk space to simulate extra memory. When the system runs low on memory, it swaps a section of RAM that an idle program is using onto the hard disk to free up memory for other programs.

For more detailed description, please go through the below link,

http://kb.iu.edu/data/aagb.html

Answer (score 0):

If you use Vim put this in your vimrc

```
set nobackup
set nowritebackup
```

If you use Emacs, put this in your .emacs.

```
(setq make-backup-files nil)
```

Then there is no backup file.